# Clear/destroy all session upon menu button click with smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

I know there is a tag to read the session`smarty.session..` tag but is there tag for destroying the session, like `smarty.session.destroy`?

What I want is when I click on menu button `Data` to destroy all stored sessions and start over with clean session.

This is the button that I have

```
<a href="/data.php" {if $smarty.server.PHP_SELF == "/data.php"}class="selected"{/if}><span>{php}echo __('Data'){/php}</span></a>
```

I have session destroy in my PHP code where I detect if there is addition parameter in the URL to destroy it and re-load the page with clean session but I don't know if there is such thing for buttons. This is my php

```
if((isset($_GET['data'])) {     
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: data.php");
    exit;
}
```

So, if user is on `https://example.com/data.php?data` and refresh the page will load `https://example.com/data.php` with destroyed sessions.

How can I accomplish the same with the menu button click?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one quick (perhaps ugly) "hack". You can change your button like this:

```
<a href="/data.php?data" {if $smarty.server.PHP_SELF == "/data.php?data"}class="selected"{/if}><span>{php}echo __('Data'){/php}</span></a>
```

This way you actually will pass the same parameter with the URL (like the one you expect in the `if` condition) and when you click on the button it will be cleaned and redirected to `/data.php` from the if condition. You will get one extra redirect on the button click.